# Rails association definition has "magic number"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am an beginner/intermediate Rails developer and I have inherited a large Rails project. While digging through the codebase I found that one of our models has association definitions that rely on a hard-coded ID:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_rels, :class_name => 'EntityAccountRel', :conditions => 'entity_account_rels.entity_type_id=1'
  has_many :vendor_rels, :class_name => 'EntityAccountRel', :conditions => 'entity_account_rels.entity_type_id=2'

  has_many :customers, :through => :customer_rels, :source => :entity
  has_many :vendors, :through => :vendor_rels, :source => :entity
```

customer and vendor are both Entities, with a relationship to Account (through EntityAccountRel). They are distinguished from one another by entity_type_id, which refers to EntityType, a model whose few members are static enough to let us get away with referring to them by hard-coded ids. I recognize this is a bad practice, but I'm wondering about the 'best' way to refactor:

1) redefine the association definition to use a subquery like so:

```
has_many :customer_rels, :class_name => 'EntityAccountRel', :conditions => 'entity_account_rels.entity_type_id=(select id from entity_type where name="Customer")'
```

This is the most obvious solution to me, but also seems terribly inelegant and likely inefficient as well

2) define a scope on EntityAccountRel like so:

```
scope :customer, joins(:entity_type).where('entity_type.code="CUST"')
```

and then somehow tie this to the association definition:

```
has_many :customer_rels, :class_name => 'EntityAccountRel', :scope => :customer
```

this doesn't work, (Unknown key(s): scope (ArgumentError)) but seems like maybe there would be support for it if I knew how to define the association correctly

3) set up an inheritance relationship on EntityAccountRel, obviating the need for entity_type_id (and maybe EntityType as well):

```
class CustomerAccountRel < EntityAccountRel
```

This would simplify my association definition but it seems like a major refactor with far-reaching implications. Plus I'm told to use inheritance cautiously, as it can make code difficult to understand.

These are all the options I've come up with, but I think I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The most obvious thing to consider is whether or not the ROI is actually worth it. DB seeding solves this problem, as would loading them up on init if there's something else you can use besides just the ID, like a string.

Comment: You make a good point about ROI - ultimately, it's probably not worth the effort, but I've got some down time and I'm trying to develop my own design skills as well as contribute to this project.

Comment: The "best" solution really depends on stuff I probably don't know. The efficiency would be determined more by indexing then much else. I'd probably consider defining the id values as named values in enums or constants during app startup if the concerns are just integrity and efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

`EntityType#id` seems to be considered static and strongly related to code behavior, so you could give them names as constants:

```
class EntityType
  CUSTOMER = 1
  VENDOR = 2
end
```

and then just substitute the magic number by the constant. That is quick and gives you a good return as you can reference that in other parts of the code easily. I'd keep all references to these constants in the model layer.

Comment: This could also be done dynamically on startup to remove one source of brittle-ness if there's a useful human-readable string associated with each value.